# Correct or wrong?: "When I will meet him, I will explain."

Tags: meaning-in-context, conditional-constructions, future-constructions

### Background

I think the present simple is usually used after *when* if it's like a condition.

E.g.:

> I'll call you **when I arrive**. (correct)
> I'll call you **when I will arrive**. (wrong)

However, on [english-corpora.org](https://www.english-corpora.org/), I found a sentence in which an expression like a wrong example above is used:

> **When I will meet him**, I will explain.

### Question

Is the sentence I found correct or wrong? If it's correct, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It‘s wrong.

I‘m pretty sure it was just a typo, because as far as I see there is no reason this rule wouldn‘t apply in this case.

It should be “When I meet him, I will explain”